# Five Lemma with category theory

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I know how to prove the 5 Lemma by diagram chasing. I would be interested in seeing a proof which only uses category theory. Does anybody know some reference where this is done?

Comment: http://therisingsea.org/notes/DiagramChasingInAbelianCategories.pdf might help to get ideas?

Comment: Also see http://mathoverflow.net/q/6749/2060 or http://blog.jpolak.org/?p=704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first paper on abelian categories is "Exact Categories and Duality" by D. A. Buchsbaum. It was published in 1955, two years before Grothendieck's famous Tohoku paper. The section 5 is about "fundamental lemmas" such as the Nine Lemma (5.5), the Snake lemma (5.8) and the Five Lemma (5.9). The proofs are direct using the definition of an abelian category (called "exact category" by Buchsbaum, this term was used later by Quillen), in particular they use - of course - no elements.