# Non-elementwise Proof for Decomposition of a Module into Direct Sum of Kernel and Image of an Idempotent Morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, alternative-proof, direct-sum

This is actually [P. Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter $0$"](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104), exercise ${\rm III}.6.3$

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module and $p\colon M\to M$ an $R$-module homomorphism such that $p^2=p$. (Such a map is called a *projection*). Prove that $M\cong\ker p~\oplus~{\rm im}~p$.

The standard approach is more or less the following: let $x\in M$, then $x-p(x)\in M$ and by the given property we deduce that $p(x-p(x))=p(x)-p(x)=0$ and therefore $x-p(x)\in\ker p$. Now we can write every element as $x=(x-p(x))+p(x)$ and the rest are routine verifications. ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566685/a-module-as-an-external-direct-product-of-the-kernel-and-image-of-an-idempotent) is a reference regarding "standard approach").

Anyway, in the spirit of Aluffi's book, I was wondering if there is a different approach. More precisely, is it possible to deduce $M\cong\ker p~\oplus~{\rm im}~p$ only from $p^2=p$ *not* using the elementwise approach. I was thinking about constructing morphisms $\alpha,\beta$ (somehow related to $p$) such that $0\rightarrow\ker p\overset\alpha\rightarrow M\overset\beta\rightarrow{\rm im}~p\rightarrow0$ splits. An evident choice would be the inclusion arrow $\iota\colon\ker p\to M$ and $p$ itself, respectively, but I was not able to deduce anything else than trivialities from hereon.

> Is this doable? Does anyone has a reference, where this approach is followed? Or do I miss something (maybe obvious) which prevents one from doing it without elements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical short exact sequence 
$$0 \to \ker p \xrightarrow{i} M \xrightarrow{p}  \text{im}~p \to 0$$
is split, because $\sigma : M \to \ker p$ defined by $\sigma = 1_M-p$ (is well defined because $p^2=p$) is a section for the sequence (this is, $\sigma i = 1_{\ker p}$) and thus by the splitting lemma, the sequence is split exact

Comment: Well, I think that is more or less what I was looking for. Thank you kindly!

Comment: I just edited it so it is completely free of any elements. This way, the proof is the same in all abelian categories (since the splitting lemma is valid in all abelian categories)

Comment: IIRC the proof of the Splitting Lemma does require some sort of diagram chase, doesn't it? I actually thought about using the Splitting Lemma somehow, but wasn't able to find an appropriate section of $p$ (now, that I see it, it's a mystery to me how I missed that one as I used the same idea in the "standard approach").

Comment: You can prove the splitting lemma with diagram chasing in $R$-mod and then use the Freyd-Mitchell theorem, but you can also prove it using only the properties of an abelian category: start with a short exact sequence $0 \to A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{c} C \to 0$ and a section $s: B \to A$ such that $sa=1_A$. The morphisms $s$ and $c$ let you build a morphism $f:B \to A \oplus C$ such that $\pi_C f =c$ and $\pi_A f = s$. The idea is proving that the arrows $1_A$, $f$, $1_C$ form an isomorphism between the exact sequences $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ and $0 \to A \to A\oplus C \to C \to 0$

Comment: Perfect! I've to admit that I only know about the Splitting Lemma by name and purpose and am not that confident with the details of its proof. However, thank you for your detailed explanation! Then, indeed, we've an element*free* proof :D

Comment: (+)  one has to check that $\pi_C f =c$ and that $i_A = fa$. The first one has already been seen and for the second one, $i_A= i_A sa =i_A \pi_A f a = fa$. The last thing to be checked is that f is an isomoprhism for this, use the 5 lemma or the snake lemma, which can be proven in an abelian category without embedding thoerems: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1650/martin-brandenburg

Comment: Is it intended that you link to the profile page of a particular user or did you meant to refer to a specific post?

Comment: No, it's just that I'm a bit new to math stack. This is the post i referred to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606806/five-lemma-with-category-theory

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for the link though. And, by the way, welcome to MSE! :)